What is the reason behind Venkateshwara Swamis Avatharam?
What are the reasons given in the Puranas? Did Rama gave boon to Vedhavathi in Tretha Yugam? Did Krushna give boon to Yashodha? Or is the reason his Karunyam on his devotees?
